# toggle html login/register form when clicking button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Im making a website which requires uers to login or register if they dont have an account.

I have the following code so far for the login page

```
<span href="#" class="button" id="toggle-login">Log in</span>

<div id="login">
  <h1>Log in</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="userID" placeholder="UserID" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
  </form>
</div>
```

and i have Javascript (below) that should hide the login form when clicking on the log in button at the top
however it doesnt seem to hide the login form.

```
$('#toggle-login').click(function(){
  $('#login').toggle();
});
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me to toggle-hide and unhide the form and if theres a way to have two forms on one page where the user can either hide the login form and display the register form and vice versa

My whole page looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Form</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <span href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="toggle-login">Log in</span>
        <div id="login">
            <h1>Log in</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="userID" placeholder="UserID" />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#toggle-login').click(function(){
                $('#login').toggle();
            });
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your code does work perfectly - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e89p32pn/)

Comment: It doesnt seem to work when i put it in notepad++
unless im not linking the javascript file correctly with the html file

Comment: Perhaps the rest of code from the page, we might be able to find another error that is causing your issue not related to this snippet.

Comment: Try `console.log()` in the `.click` function. Maybe jQuery isn't loaded or the JS-file doesn't load as it should?

Comment: Ive edited my original post to show the whole html code im using on the login page

Comment: I can't find the jQuery script

Comment: is $('#toggle-login').click(function(){ $('#login').toggle(); }); not jQuery? or Javascript? Sorry im not that good at html/javascript

Comment: it is jQuery code, but you should also add a jQuery library to your page.  [**How to start with jQuery?**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)

Comment: Ah yes thank you! managed to get it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the jQuery library if you are going to use it. Add this to your head section and you should be fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to toggle between forms? for example i have two forms on one page. I want to be able to hide one form and have the other form shown.

Comment: Yes, just add another line to your click function like this
    $("<id for your other element>").toggle();

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="toggle-login">
<form>
<!-- FORM ELEMTNS -->
<input typre="text">
</form>    
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="toggle login" >
```

Jquery:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
$("#toggle-login").toggle();
});
```

Also include the jquery library at head session.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```